# Pandas Multiple "group by" and operations on values

Tags: pandas, group-by

A have a dataset

```
ID    ID2    var1
 1      p      10
 1      r       5
 1      p       9
 2      p       7
 2      r       6
 2      r       7
```

I need to certify that in each Nº ID the difference between (the sum of var1 by "p") and (the sum of var1 by "r") is more than 0. In other words, I need to group by ID and apply arithmetic operations between values grouped by ID2.
Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: I think you should clarify a little bit more the question. 
Do you want to just "Group by" or you want to make arithmetical operations between columns and group by at the same time?

Comment: Agree. I will explain below

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
"""ID   ID2    var1
 1      p      10
 1      r       5
 1      p       9
 2      p       7
 2      r       6
 2      r       7""")).set_index("ID")


df2 = df.pivot_table(values = "var1", index="ID", columns="ID2", aggfunc='sum')

# Example operatin -- difference
df2['diff'] = df2['p'] - df2['r']
df2
```

Result

```
ID2   p   r  diff
ID               
1    19   5    14
2     7  13    -6
```

Comment: I believe you need to set `aggfunc='sum'` to your pivot_table. The default function in pivot_table is `mean`, the O.P. needs `sum`

Comment: Added aggfunc='sum' as noted by @Terry

Comment: Thank you for the idea to apply pivot operator. I've never used it in pandas! Good to know. Great

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.groupby` and `.diff()` to calculate the difference after the groupby.

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'ID2']).var1.sum().diff()

Out[72]: 
ID  ID2
1   p       NaN
    r     -14.0
2   p       2.0
    r       6.0
Name: var1, dtype: float64
```

You can also add an indicator, which shows if the difference was greater than 0 with `np.where`, before that we use `.reset_index` to get our `var1` column back.

```
groupby = df.groupby(['ID', 'ID2']).var1.sum().diff().reset_index()

groupby['indicator'] = np.where(groupby.var1 > 0, 'yes', 'no')

print(groupby)
   ID ID2  var1 indicator
0   1   p   NaN        no
1   1   r -14.0        no
2   2   p   2.0       yes
3   2   r   6.0       yes
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, but would fail if there were other values in `var2` between those wanting to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
df.groupby(['ID','ID2']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).diff()
Out[174]: 
        var1
ID ID2      
1  p     NaN
   r   -14.0
2  p     NaN
   r     6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.DataFrame([[1,'p',10], [1,'r',5], [1,'p',9 ],
                        [2,'p',7 ], [2,'r',6 ], [2,'r',7 ]], 
                        columns=['ID', 'ID2', 'var1'])
```

You can make a cross tabulation:

```
    df=pd.crosstab(df.ID, [df.ID2,df.var1], margins=True)

    >>>df

    ID2   p        r       All
    var1  7  9 10  5  6  7    
    ID                        
    1     0  1  1  1  0  0   3
    2     1  0  0  0  1  1   3
    All   1  1  1  1  1  1   6
```

With no margins:

```
    pd.crosstab(df.ID, [df.ID2,df.var1])

    ID2   p        r      
    var1  7  9  10 5  6  7 
    ID                    
    1     0  1  1  1  0  0
    2     1  0  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys very much for all your suggestions! I'm almost there...:)
I was trying all the codes. 
I think I was not clear when explaining what the output I want. I think for the practical case I'm working on it would be useful to add an additional variable or two into the original list like this (below) This allows me to take decisions regarding IDs with negative differences in following steps.

```
 output:
 ID    ID2    var1   var2(diff)   var_control
 1      p      10          14              0
 1      r       5          14              0
 1      p       9          14              0
 2      p       7          -6              1
 2      r       6          -6              1
 2      r       7          -6              1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i did it with all your help. Thank you so much! You are awesome

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [23, 23, 23, 43, 43],
                   'id2': ["r", "p", "p", "p", "r"],
                   'var1': [4, 6, 7, 1, 3]})

print(df)

df2 = df.pivot_table(values = "var1", index="id", columns="id2", aggfunc='sum')
df2['diff'] = df2['p'] - df2['r']

df["var_2"]=df['id'].map(df2["diff"])

df['control'] = np.where(df['var_2']<0, 1, 0)
```